# Mongodb is slow on 8 million rows collection

Tags: mongodb, optimization, database-schema, nosql

I have 8 milion rows of collection, and I am new to mongoDB.
It loads 20 rows really slowly...

What should I do do speed it up?

Comment: When you say "loads 20 rows" - are you talking about querying or inserting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you need to add index.

[Optimization Guidelines](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization)

Answer (score 2):

Need more informations.Just like server's ram。

Optimize Step:
1.Index your query field。
2.Check the index's storage size。If the index's size larger than RAM。MongoDB need to read data by disk I/O.So slower.

8 milion documents is not large。It is not a big  deal。